# ObjectsPerPage for UITableView in a UIViewController Using Parse.com

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, parse-platform

I'm using a `UITableView` which I put in a `UIViewController` to display data that I have uploaded on Parse.com. I have it working perfectly except one thing. I have about 700 rows of data on Parse.com but my `UITableView` is only showing the first 100 (the amount for the first page of data on parse.com). It is not showing the rest of the data on the other pages.

I want to adjust the `objectsPerPage` so I'm able to display all of my data. Am I able to do this with how my project is set up or do I have to switch to using a `UITableViewController` that is a subclass of `PFQueryTableViewController`? I just want the `UITableView` to display ALL of my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`objectsPerPage` is a property on the `PFQueryTableViewController`. As I understand your question, you are not using this. But the default query limit on parse.com is 100. All you need to do is to set the limit to i.e. 1000 before running your query:

```
query.limit = 1000;
```

and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Below is my solution which probably isn't the most elegant but it works. fetcingNewData is a BOOL in order not to send a new query before the last one returns something, since scrollViewDidScroll will be triggered multiple times.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (myTableView.contentOffset.y >= (myTableView.contentSize.height - myTableView.bounds.size.height))
    {
        //NSLog(@"Scrolled to bottom...");
        if (!fetchingNewData && hasOldPosts) {
            queryLimit +=10;
            [self loadChatbord:FALSE]; //the parameter sets if the scrollView will scroll to top or bottom
        }
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) {
        //NSLog(@"Scrolled to top...");
        if (!fetchingNewData) {
            [self loadChatbord:TRUE];
        }
    }
}
```